How to Restrict Past Dates and Set Conditions on Start Date & End Date in Form Builder?
I'm using the CiviCRM form builder to create a form, and I need help with setting conditions on the date fields, currently I’m able to select a start date that is before the current date, I want to achieve the following:
Prevent Past Dates: I want to restrict the "Start Date" and "End Date" fields so that users cannot select past dates.
End Date Validation: The "End Date" should either match the "Start Date" or be a future date. It should never be earlier than the "Start Date".

I couldn't find an option in the form builder to apply these conditions directly. Does anyone know how to implement these restrictions?
Thank you!
